# App crashing after trying to load 10 webpages with UIWebView

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview

I'm making an app where you can order food. I made it to where the checkout is in a `UIWebView` page on paypal. The problem is their are 9 or 10 diffrent webpages being loaded at once. I was wondering if their is a way to make it only load when needed.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!
    @IBOutlet weak var webView1: UIWebView!
    @IBOutlet weak var webView2: UIWebView!
    @IBOutlet weak var webView3: UIWebView!
    @IBOutlet weak var webView4: UIWebView!
    @IBOutlet weak var webView5: UIWebView!
    @IBOutlet weak var webView6: UIWebView!
    @IBOutlet weak var webView7: UIWebView!
    @IBOutlet weak var webView8: UIWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        let url = NSURL(string: "https://mms-lunch-order.000webhostapp.com/12count/pay.html")
        let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
        webView.loadRequest(request)

        let url1 = NSURL(string: "https://mms-lunch-order.000webhostapp.com/spicychicken6th/pay2.html")
        let request1 = NSURLRequest(URL: url1!)
        webView1.loadRequest(request1)

        let url2 = NSURL(string: "https://mms-lunch-order.000webhostapp.com/chickensandwhich6th/pay3.html")
        let request2 = NSURLRequest(URL: url2!)
        webView2.loadRequest(request2)

        let url3 = NSURL(string: "https://mms-lunch-order.000webhostapp.com/12count7/pay4.html")
        let request3 = NSURLRequest(URL: url3!)
        webView3.loadRequest(request3)

        let url4 = NSURL(string: "https://mms-lunch-order.000webhostapp.com/spicychicken7/pay9.html")
        let request4 = NSURLRequest(URL: url4!)
        webView4.loadRequest(request4)

        let url5 = NSURL(string: "https://mms-lunch-order.000webhostapp.com/chickensandwhich7/pay7.html")
        let request5 = NSURLRequest(URL: url5!)
        webView5.loadRequest(request5)

        let url6 = NSURL(string: "https://mms-lunch-order.000webhostapp.com/12count8/pay5.html")
        let request6 = NSURLRequest(URL: url6!)
        webView6.loadRequest(request6)

        let url7 = NSURL(string: "https://mms-lunch-order.000webhostapp.com/spicychicken8/pay10.html")
        let request7 = NSURLRequest(URL: url7!)
        webView7.loadRequest(request7)

        let url8 = NSURL(string: "https://mms-lunch-order.000webhostapp.com/chickensandwhich8/pay8.html")
        let request8 = NSURLRequest(URL: url8!)
        webView8.loadRequest(request8)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using 9 web views at once? Just use 1 and load each page one after the other as needed.

Comment: how would I go about doing that?

Comment: Why would you load all at once? How user going to read all at once?, just load when it's visible

Comment: How would i do this?
 im also getting this error EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION

fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb)

Comment: looking fearther, i see that webView1 is = to nil . how should i fix this?

Comment: you can use custom cell with webview on Tabaleview

Answer (score 0):

This is comment because I don't have enough reputation.

I think may be @IBOutlet is not connected properly,can you please check that

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are navigating to this web view from a previous page, and you only intend to check out for the item you chose. If this is not the case, then let me know and I will adjust this answer.

In that case, remove all but one webview. I would set a variable on this viewcontroller called foodUrlString.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!

var foodUrlString = String()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    if let url = NSURL(string: foodUrlString) {
      let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
      webView.loadRequest(request)
    } else {
    //if URL does not work for some reason, do something here like show error loading view or something 
    }
}
```

When you are about to navigate to this viewcontroller and you know what you want to buy, set the URL String for that foodUrlString property.

For instance, if you are presenting this viewcontroller, set it right before you present it from previous viewcontroller

```
viewController.foodUrlString = "http://food.com"
```

As far as your web view being nil, leave only one web view. In storyboard, control click on the top most view in the hierarchy and delete any unlinked outlets.

Comment: Thanks, I was wondering how i would make the we link vary? I have it setup where the select the school grade, then they select their item. their are diffrent items for each grade. Thanks:D

Comment: Where do they select the school grade and their item? On another page? Or in another view on this view controller?

Comment: another view controller for every tab( grade, items for each grade, etc.)

Comment: the thing I typed above, viewController.foodUrlString is how you would change the url. So wherever you are presenting the next web view controller, you would set the property on that web view controller before presenting it, as I showed at the end of my answer. So if there is an IBAction, right before presentViewController or pushViewController, you would set viewController.foodUrlString to what you need it to be.